# Opening recent files issue

Tags: vimrc, gvim, filesystem, multiple-files, file-operations

TLDR: How can I open a file from the list of recent files without going to the end of the list to get to the prompt for file number?

In order to open recent files, I do `:bro ol` and then when I see the file that I want to open, I have to press <kbd>Space</kbd> to get to the bottom of the list and to see the prompt for entering the file number. I was wondering if there is a faster way; possibly being able to get the prompt for file number on the first page of recent files, rather than pressing space until I get to the end of the page.

**bonus question:**

What does `:ol` do? Does it just list the recent files and a file cannot be opened from the list?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of (or possible solution) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937545/use-search-in-browse-oldfiles-list . `:ol` list old files, see `:help :oldfiles`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)'s `:History`.